# My linked list is not working correctly

Tags: c++, oop

following is my code for the program that will print out the random position contained values of nodes of a linked list. The problem is that my list is not printing the complete result. It prints only one result and thus. Please tell me where i am wrong.

```
int main(){

    List* n;

    int value=3;
    int *counter=0;

    collect(value,counter);

    for(int i=0; i<&counter; i++);
    {
        count<<"\n Shuffled: "<< n.pickanddestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't even compile. `n` is (unnecessarily) declared as a pointer so the expression `n.pickanddestroy` should yield a compiler error.

Comment: Since `n` is a pointer, you will need to use the `->` operator, such as `n->pickanddestroy()`.

Comment: Also, since `counter` is a pointer, the expression `&counter` returns the location of the pointer (a.k.a. address of the pointer, not the pointer's contents).  So you are testing `i` against the address of a pointer.

Comment: The `List` pointer, `n`, is never initialized.  Dereferencing the uninitialized pointer produces *Undefined Behavior*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the semicolon at the end of the first line of your for loop.

Comment: thanks it worked. i missed that.